# Need to change the value of a drop down choice box

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript

I have a list in sharepoint. One column is a choice box for pending, approved, denied. I need to create a method to approve all on the click of a button. I cant figure out how because it doesnt represent to the browser itself as a choice box. Its all in a table inside the cell. See the code below.

```
<div id="jsgrid_combobox" class="combobox-placeholder" style="position:absolute; visibility: inherit; border: 0px; top: 33px; left: 64px; direction: ltr; min-width: 115px; width: 115px; height: 29px; background-color: transparent;"><input type="text" class="cb-textbox " dir="ltr" style="height: 25px; width: 82px;"><input type="button" class="combobox-img" value="▼" tabindex="-1" title="Dropdown" dir="ltr" style="height: 29px;"><div class="combobox-dropdown" style="visibility: hidden; z-index: 0; max-width: 200px; margin-left: 0px; top: 1px; display: none;"><div class="combobox-tablewrapper" style="height: 100px;"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="combobox-panel-table"><tbody><tr class="cb-dp-rw"><td><div></div></td><td style="border-right-width: 0px;"><div class="cb-dp-rw-selected"><div style="white-space: nowrap; padding: 4px;"><span title="Pending" class="jsgrid-control-text">Pending</span></div></div></td></tr><tr class="cb-dp-rw"><td><div></div></td><td style="border-right-width: 0px;"><div class=""><div style="white-space: nowrap; padding: 4px;"><span title="Approved" class="jsgrid-control-text">Approved</span></div></div></td></tr><tr class="cb-dp-rw"><td><div></div></td><td style="border-right-width: 0px;"><div><div style="white-space: nowrap; padding: 4px;"><span title="Rejected" class="jsgrid-control-text">Rejected</span></div></div></td></tr><tr class="cb-dp-rw"><td><div></div></td><td style="border-right-width: 0px;"><div><div style="white-space: nowrap; padding: 4px;"><span title="Additional Info Needed" class="jsgrid-control-text">Additional Info Needed</span></div></div></td></tr></tbody></table></div><a href="#" dir="ltr" class="combobox-link">Edit List Items</a></div></div>
```

List URL:   Expense%20Reports%20v2/Manager.aspx#InplviewHash5fa282cd-555d-4129-9b53-  726afb8b5ac8=ShowInGrid%3DTrue

so i would get for a name of the list of "Expense Reports v2" if i am doing it correctly. I am assuming i can ignore all the other stuff after like the /Manager.aspx etc.

Below is the code i am trying to use as directed, but its not working. All the variables remain undefined throughout its execution.

```
$().SPServices.SPUpdateMultipleListItems({
    listName: "Expense Reports v2",
    CAMLQuery: "<Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Approval_' /></OrderBy</Query>",
    batchCmd: "Update",
    valuepairs: [["Approval_x0020_Status", "Approved"]]
    });
```

Comment: Is this is what you required? http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/146465/select-all-check-boxes-in-choice-field-on-document-library-form-using-jquery

Comment: updated my answer please take a look

Answer (score 1):

You can use SpServices and use SPUpdateMultipleListItems() to change the column value to approve for all the items or some specific items based on your query. It would be something like this below:

```
<script language="javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script language="javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.SPServices-0.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function ApproveALL()
{
    $().SPServices.SPUpdateMultipleListItems({
                   listName: “Expense Reports v2”,
                   CAMLQuery: "<Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' /></OrderBy></Query>", //You can write more specific query
                   valuepairs: [["Approval_x0020_Status", "Approved"]],
                   completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
        alert("Completed");
    }
     });
}
</script>
<button onclick="ApproveALL()">Click me</button>
```

You can wrap the above in a function and call it on button click.

[SpServices](https://spservices.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Ok, so i put this code into a function that i am calling on button click. However, my code never executes and i cant figure out where im going wrong. I have tried to use multiple values for listname and valuepairs for the column name but nothing works. The error i get in the debugger is:
    Unable to get property 'SPUpdateMultipleListItems' of undefined or null reference

It is almost as if its not referenceing the call to the SPservice. Is there any way that i may not have referenced a js file?

Comment: did you refer the spservices jquery file?

Comment: I dont think i have, and that is probably the problem

Comment: Ok, so no i have a reference to both

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://sandbox.expresslocations.com/operations/jsfiles/jquery.SPServices-2014.02.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://sandbox.expresslocations.com/operations/jsfiles/jquery.SPServices-2014.02.js"></script>

And i have made it a bit farther, now when i am watching the code in the debugger it is at least executing without error, but its not working. It seems as though it cant find info or something because none of the variables, i.e. listName:, CAMLQuery, all say undefined at each step.

Comment: Refer jquery file too. Then please try some different key value pairs too.

Comment: Ok, i referenced <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: http://www.enjoysharepoint.com/Articles/Details/sharepoint-2013-online-getlistitems-using-spservices-21122.aspx

Comment: Ok, i think at this point the issue is not knowing what to reference field wise. In your CAML query, you are ordering by the field ID, but i dont have a field named ID. Also, i am finding conflicting articles telling me how to reference the list. The list name is either "Expense Reports" or "Expense Reports v2", or "b612de4b-f85c-4492-8877-8c2b07ae187d" depending on how and where i look at it. And the fields, in this case "Approval_x0020_Status" or "Approval Status". Some background, someone else created this list, and they hired me on and my first test is to add the button that approves all.

Comment: http://www.enjoysharepoint.com/Articles/Details/sharepoint-online-add-update-delete-item-from-list-using-spservices-21115.aspx

Comment: You'll need to use internal names, so it should be the complex one, for list name check the url of the list

Comment: I edited my initial post to include the url to the list and what i would believe the name of the list to be. Correct me if i am wrong. Thanks!

Comment: I have changed the call around to match what you have above. It still isnt working, but it isnt giving me any kind of error to debug or know where im going wrong. I set breakpoints at the beginning of the call $().SPServices.SPUpdateMultipleListItems and like i said, the variables like listName never become assigned, they are always undefined. Can you give me any suggestions on locating the problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25876/discussion-between-taran-goel-and-user519670).