# Get the Checkbox checked status on submit button click in SP 2010 list form

Tags: javascript, jquery, list-form, newform

Am using checkbox multichoice field in my `newform.aspx` and in presaveaction call am doing the below code:

```
      function PreSaveAction() 
          {
          var dt3;
           var dt4;
             var dt5;
             var dt6Date;
              var dt7StartDate;
             var dt8Date;
             var estimatedsizein;
            var currentStatusChoiceField;
             var flagGeneric =true;

            var ORCBIEPMcheckedonsubmit  = 
            jQuery("input[name$='ctl00$m$g_505f6778_755e_45e6_
            b8da_a2acdd7adae3$ctl00$ctl05$ctl17$ctl00$
           ctl00$ctl04$ctl00$ctl00']").is(':checked');
           alert(ORCBIEPMcheckedonsubmit  + ' is the orcbiepm value 
      checked on submit');
```

I tried with the name,-name$- which i got from `F12 dev tools`, but i am unable to get the value of checked status of this checkbox, am having 16 checkboxes in this  SPFieldChecboxfield. but nothing happened.
am struggling to find out  how to get teh checked status of each checkboxes.

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with SharePoint. You have a problem with jQuery and Selectors. https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: This may help http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/146465/select-all-check-boxes-in-choice-field-on-document-library-form-using-jquery