# 'select All' option in SharePoint list column filters

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

I need a 'Select All' option in a SharePoint list column filter.
So that if I click 'Select All' option then all filters of check boxes has to select.

Comment: use jquery to get this done

Comment: Can you please explain in brief to achieve this with jquery

Comment: Those filters are dynamically built, so you need to hook into that process. It is not *just* changing the UI a bit with some jQuery calls. Given your previous comment I dare to say you will not be able to built this yourself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select All check-boxes in choice field on document library form using jquery](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/146465/select-all-check-boxes-in-choice-field-on-document-library-form-using-jquery)