# How to get the "Select All" checkbox for custom list newform and editform?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server

Is there any out-of-the-box feature or custom solution using jQuery?

How to get "Select All and Deselect All" functionality for checkboxes in sharepoint 2013(on premises)custom list?

and also please let me know where should i keep the code.
[image]

Comment: This may help you http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/146465/select-all-check-boxes-in-choice-field-on-document-library-form-using-jquery

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable this check box setting under List Settings --> Go to the view where you want to enable the check box. Under Tabular View --> Check Allow individual item checkboxes option.

Comment: Please find the attached screenshot.

Comment: Product is a choice column? If you are creating custom list using visual studio?

Comment: Yes, Product is choice column. I am not using visual studio.

Comment: Please refer this link: Hope it helps...... https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/9139f622-87d8-4653-b9d3-f4e451ece1d2/checkbox-and-select-all?forum=sharepointdevelopmentlegacy

Comment: If you need to select all checkbox by default, use this link for your reference: http://www.sharepointindepth.com/sharepoint-form-checkboxes-to-be-all-checked-by-default/------Also check these links also : http://spjsblog.com/2010/02/25/add-invert-check-all-and-uncheck-all-to-a-multichoice-checkbox-column-or-the-entire-form/                                   http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/146465/select-all-check-boxes-in-choice-field-on-document-library-form-using-jquery